# Custom Ellipsize a TextView

Tags: android, textview

I want to ellipsize a text in a TextView.

Usually there are START,END,MIDDLE... .

I want to cut the text after 5 chracters. How can I modify this method?

Comment: how about you manually cut your string using substring(0, 4) and add three dots at the end using apend("...") for the strings which have more than five characters ?

Comment: this is what i've thought,too. But I need the text in good order. This is for a Spinner

Answer (score -1, accepted):

android:ellipsize="" use this one

Comment: can you enlarge that?

Comment: android:ellipsize"none" or android:ellipsize"start" or android:ellipsize"middle" or android:ellipsize"end" or android:ellipsize"marquee" choose from these

Comment: this is ellipsize in xml I know. but that isn't an answer of my question

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

android:maxEms="5"
adding android:ellipsize="end" if u wanna